# Application of Egoroff's thm on infinite measure

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

[image]

This is what I have solved. My professor actually said this question need a condition for which m(E) is finite. He is keep saying that m,k cannot be fixed after reordering. But I think that there is no problem in my question. (Indeed this gives a great stress to me...) Anyway I want to check who is right.

Comment: How do you define $E \cap (-m,m)$? Basically, if I read well, you just said Egorov’s theorem solved the question instead of proving it.

Comment: Well in class we already showed that the result hods for finite measure. It's pretty easy by Egorov in this case. Suppose m(E) is finite. Then for each k in N, there is measureable Fk in E s.t m(Fk) <1/n and fn uniformly convergesto f on E\Fk. Put E(k+1)=E\Fk for each k in N, and put E1=intersection(Fk, k in N). Then we can easliy find that {Ek} is a desired set. This is how I got {E(m,k)} for each m in N

Comment: Oh I add this for avoiding confusion. I'm not trying to say that Egoroff's thm holds for infinite measure (this cannot be true by considering {X[0,n)}. All I'm trying to verify is weather we can solve excercise31 without the condition that m(E) is finite though my professor told me that we must add finite measure condition to this excercise.